# creating virtual mousepad in jquery with click and hover events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi Friends i am very very new to javascript and and J Query . now i want to create virtual mouse pad . i am created two div's  one for mouse pad and second one is container in container i am taken another div for act as a cursor(class name is follower) . 
in mouse pad div when ever mouse move follower div moving relative to the mouse position. now i want to generate click event using virtual cursor means click the buttons using follower.
    
                
                     
                    
                        Button1
                        Button2
                    
                
        
                MousePad

this is my js code

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15;
$('.container1').mousemove(function(e){
  var offset = $('.container1').offset();
   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);
    mouseX=mouseX*3;
    mouseY=mouseY*3;
   if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
   if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
});

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp);
    yp += (mouseY - yp) ;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

    }, 30);
$('.buttons span').bind('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('title'));  

  });
```

JSbin Link

http://jsbin.com/AGAquhej/2/edit  for code

http://jsbin.com/AGAquhej/1  Demo

i want generate click event using follower(moving in mouse pad)
can any one solve the problem how to generate fake click events

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you could use jquery .trigger. See example here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: how can it is possible using .trigger if possible write some sample code it's give more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the some collision detection code from this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180865/1481489 the following may work (untested, description is in the comments):

```
var overlaps = (function () { // this is the collision detection code
    function getPositions( elem ) {
        var pos, width, height;
        pos = $( elem ).position();
        width = $( elem ).width();
        height = $( elem ).height();
        return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] ];
    }

    function comparePositions( p1, p2 ) {
        var r1, r2;
        r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
        r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
        return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
    }

    return function ( a, b ) {
        var pos1 = getPositions( a ),
            pos2 = getPositions( b );
        return comparePositions( pos1[0], pos2[0] ) && comparePositions( pos1[1], pos2[1] );
    };
})();

$('.container1').mousemove(function(e){
  var offset = $('.container1').offset();
   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);
    mouseX=mouseX*3;
    mouseY=mouseY*3;
   if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
   if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
});

$('.container1').click(function(){
    proxyTriggerEvent('click');
});

function proxyTriggerEvent(eventName) {
    $('.container').find('a,input,.buttons span')
    .each(function() { // and loop through them all for testing
        if ( overlaps(follower,this) ) { // collision detection for each item
            $(this).trigger(eventName); // click the specific element
            return false; // break out of the loop
        }
    });
}
```

---

**Update:**

- Fixed a bug where the selector was not targeting the buttons. I misread the tag as `<span class="button1">` but it is really `<span title="button1">`. The selector is now `.buttons span` instead of `.button1,.button2`.
- Removed the unnecessary filtering of follower with `.not('#follower')`
- Moved the hit detection to the click handler of `.container` - this way it isn't being run on every single interval frame, only when it really counts.
- Moved the event trigger proxy out of the click call, now any event can be triggered, and it can be called as a regular function, e.g.: `proxyTriggerEvent('mouseup');` or `proxyTriggerEvent('click');`

Comment: sorry this is not worked for me http://jsbin.com/AGAquhej/3/edit i integrated your code and tested in this link.can you check this . is any thing wrong in this code if any thing can you do the modification.

Comment: this is working fine but small problem this is not pixel perfect and i want to add hover functionality to that.if possible please modify the code

Comment: @sarath not sure if it is the best way to do it, but here's the updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/urEpESAM/4/edit also the :hover pseudo class cannot be triggered with javascript (that i know of): http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-triggering-css-pseudo-selectors-like-hover

Comment: hi i have small question how to stop direct mouse click  i want click only with trigger is any way to do it ?? please tell me

Comment: @sarath change the anonymous function within the `click()` to a named function and subsequently remove the click binding. Then when you want to "trigger" it, simply call that newly named function.

Comment: my sad i am unable to do that one if you have time can you write the code

Comment: yesterday i seen your website,blog and your resume .  that's very great you worked as a faculty in your own college

Comment: @sarath, I abstracted the trigger code. Just call `proxyTriggerEvent('click');` wherever you'd like. Also notice, I kept the `.container1` click binding; you may remove it at your discretion. (And thanks for the compliment!)

Comment: Is there a way to do this but with a touch interface, like create a mouse pad in a mobile browser?

Comment: @dvdcastro this question and answer is specific to click and hover events for the mouse, if you want it to work with a touch interface, open a new question and link it to this one :)